# What font is this? I don't seem to find this one exact

Tags: fonts, font-identification

What font is this? I don't seem to find this one exactly
I am having a hard time to find this exact[image] font

Comment: There are two different fonts but I guess you mean the largest one? Have you tried using the different font identification sites? A tip: Make an image only containing the font you want to identify and make sure the text is black and the background white.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Topline is [Suisse International Bold](https://www.swisstypefaces.com/fonts/suisse/) (almost identical to Helvetica), but the designer cut the left bar off the 't' to reduce whitespace. That's a [common way to modify a font](https://ohnotype.co/blog/type-to-logotype) into a logo.

The bottom is Eurostile Extended, the & sign is very distinctive.

Comment: Thanks, you were right

Comment: My apologies, I actually wasn't! The top font is Suisse International Bold, which is based on Helvetica and almost indistinguishable in these characters. You'll see the 'g' matches better.

Comment: I worked it out customizing Helvetica, Thanks anyway